# How can I change SMTP details globally at runtime?

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, swiftmailer

I'm using Laravel 5.5.  The nature of the website is a 'multisite' architecture where multiple websites/domains are run from the same codebase.

I've come across an issue when sending email.  I need to change the `from` `name` and `address` as well as the `transport` (SMTP, etc) options depending on which website is being viewed.  I have these details stored in a config file.

The easiest way is to just pull those details in the Controller before I call `Mail::send`/`Mail::queue` and to update them.  However, this brings back 2 issues:

1. There is a heavy reliance on remembering to actually do that every time I send any email in the code.  In short, it's not abiding by DRY.
2. I'd be forced to use `Mail::send` instead of `Mail::queue`, because the queue wouldn't have any idea of the config update from the time it was ***queued*** only from when it is ***processed*** .

How can I achieve what I am looking to do here in a clean way?

I thought about extending all of my 'Mailable' classes with a custom class that updates the SMTP details, but it doesn't look like you can update the SMTP/Transport information after the class is initiated; you can only update the `from` `name` and `address`.

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/23183

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to find a way to do this.

I had my mailable class (`ContactFormMailable`) extend a custom class, as follows:

```
<?php

namespace CustomGlobal\Mail;

use CustomGlobal\Mail\CustomMailable;
use CustomGlobal\ContactForm;

class ContactFormMailable extends CustomMailable
{
    public $contact_form;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(ContactForm $contact_form)
    {
        $this->contact_form = $contact_form;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        $view = $this->get_custom_mail_view('contact_form', $this->contact_form);

        return $this->subject('Contact Form Enquiry')
            ->view($view);
    }
}
```

You'll notice I'm calling `get_custom_mail_view`.  This is in my extended class and used to calculate the view and template I need to use for my mail, depending on the website being viewed.  In here I also set the location of my config folder.

```
<?php

namespace CustomGlobal\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Swift_Mailer;
use Swift_SmtpTransport;
use CustomGlobal\Website;
use CustomGlobal\Territory;

class CustomMailable extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $layout_view_to_serve;
    public $host_folder;

    /**
     * Override Mailable functionality to support per-user mail settings
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer  $mailer
     * @return void
     */
    public function send(Mailer $mailer)
    {
        app()->call([$this, 'build']);

        $config = config($this->host_folder .'.mail');
        // Set SMTP details for this host
        $host = $config['host'];
        $port = $config['port'];
        $encryption  = $config['encryption'];

        $transport = new Swift_SmtpTransport( $host, $port, $encryption );
        $transport->setUsername($config['username']);
        $transport->setPassword($config['password']);
        $mailer->setSwiftMailer(new Swift_Mailer($transport));

        $mailer->send($this->buildView(), $this->buildViewData(), function ($message) use($config) {
            $message->from([$config['from']['address'] => $config['from']['name']]);
            $this->buildFrom($message)
                 ->buildRecipients($message)
                 ->buildSubject($message)
                 ->buildAttachments($message)
                 ->runCallbacks($message);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the template we need to serve.
     * $entity can be any object but it must contain a 
     * $website_id and $territory_id, as that is used
     * to calculate the path.
     */
    public function get_custom_mail_view($view_filename, $entity)
    {
        if(empty($view_filename)) {
            throw new Exception('The get_custom_mail_view method requires a view to be passed as parameter 1.');
        }

        if(empty($entity->website_id) || empty($entity->territory_id)) {
            throw new Exception('The get_custom_mail_view method must be passed an object containing a website_id and territory_id value.');
        }

        // Get the website and territory
        $website = Website::findOrFail($entity->website_id);
        $territory = Territory::findOrFail($entity->territory_id);

        $view_to_serve = false;
        $layout_view_to_serve = false;

        // Be sure to replace . with _, as Laravel doesn't play nice with dots in folder names
        $host_folder = str_replace('.', '_', $website->website_domain);
        $this->host_folder = $host_folder; // Used for mail config later

        /***
            Truncated for readability.  What's in this area isn't really important to this answer.
        ***/

        $this->layout_view_to_serve = $layout_view_to_serve;

        return $view_to_serve;
    }
}
```

It's important to remember that mail can be queued.  If you do this is another way, such as setting a config at runtime, then you'll find that the process that runs the queue has no visibility/scope of your runtime config changes, and you'll end up firing out email from your default values.

I found a few answers similar to this one, which helped me out, but none of them worked completely, and some are out-dated (`Swift_SmtpTransport` is changed considerably since those answers).

Hopefully this helps someone else out.

Comment: This answer has not (in my opinion) received the recognition it rightly deserves!  Thanks @Mike - running with L8, works pretty much out of the box. +1

Comment: Glad it worked @absolute.  I'm surprised more people have come up against this.  I suspect there are a lot of emails blindly being sent using the wrong settings, as it's easy to assume the configured settings would be used when switching between queue and non-queued mail.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue where on our dev environment we use mailtrap to prevent customers from getting test emails, & we started using AWS  secrets manager to store the mailtrap credentials. We setup a listener for `Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending` - initially called `Config::set()` with `mail.username` & `mail.password` but at that point it was too late. I got it to work with the listener calling `Illuminate\Container\Container::getInstance()->make('mailer');` to get the mailer & calling its `setUsername()` & `setPassword()`, so I didn't have to override the Mailer's `send()` method.

Comment: Sounds like that would use for your use-case @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ , but not ours. Here we have dozens of mail settings depending on various criteria, something not suitable for environment variables. Essentially, we have to store our mail information at the database level - think of it like a SaaS model and we're mailing using customer details (we aren't, but similar model).